# how to join video files?

Tags: video

I have 12 parts of videos .

I want to join them in a sequence and make a single video.

Please suggest me software and steps to do this.

can i need to install adobe premier?

thank you

example videos are https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLTShW1Bm7xcM0bLdbadfpsdia5MkOEkrI

Comment: Any video editor will do, you'll just need to put them in the desired order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quicktime can do this. I tried the following steps on a Mac with two `.mov` files. 
One file was encoded with the `h264` coded, the other with `JPEG`.

Open the first video in Quicktime and just drag and drop the second video on it.
The second video will be appended to the end of the first. The timeline will be showing the different movies and a button titled `Done`.

Add all your videos in the above manner and then click `Done`. To save the result go to `File -> Export to -> Web...` and choose the destination and video settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you have money CarbonCoder does this. It is very easy, drag and drop the video, check the "stitch" box and select the output format.

Else you can use ffmpeg + avisynth.
Create an avisynth script which will just read and add the different videos:

Avisynth script:

```
vid1 = FFmpegSource2("path_to_first_video.avi")
vid2 = FFmpegSource2("path_to_second_video.avi")
vidn = FFmpegSource2("path_to_nth_video.avi")
concat = vid1 + vid2 + .. + vidn 
return concat
```

ffmpeg command

```
ffmpeg.exe -i avisynth_script.avs [ encoding options ] concatened_video.avi
```

In the example I used avi container, but avisynth supports also quicktime and other.
Find here the [Avisynth documentation](http://avisynth.org/mediawiki/Main_Page) . This will work on windows, as far as I know avisynth does not work on linux ( or in alpha stage ? ).